# Cascade.all not working with spring boot and jparepository

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I' am using Jsprepository and I can't delete row using cascade.all

> error=Internal Server Error, message=could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

*Parameter.java*

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "parameter")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Parameter {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "num")
    private Integer number;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

    @Column(name = "bool")
    private Boolean bool;

    @Column(name = "date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date date;

}
```

*Group.java*

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "group_")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Group {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parameter_id")
    private Parameter parameter;
}
```

*GroupService.java*

```
@Service
public class GroupService {

    @Autowired
    private GroupRepository groupRepository;


    public void deleteGroup(Long id){
        groupRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing @JsonInclude and then trying out again ?

Comment: @Rjiuk I tried, it didn't help

Comment: I would also try set FetchType.EAGER for experiment, maybe it is the problem that it won't load the relation which it NEEDS to delete because of ophranRemoval. No sure tho

Comment: Can you share Repository/DAO code?

Comment: public interface ParameterRepository extends JpaRepository<Parameter, Long> {}